# Clipart images for LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks

Is there any public bank of clipart images in Tikz / PSTrics, much like those found in tools like Visio?

Comment: With [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) you can download any SVG clipart from [OpenClipArt.org](http://openclipart.org/) and convert it to PDF or EPS.

Comment: @Werner: Or to TikZ, using the [Inkscape2TikZ](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) plugin.

Comment: I don't know but, by chance, I was just looking at [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=clipart%20tikz&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoftcream.oka-pu.ac.jp%2Fwp%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F02%2Fclipart4latex.pdf&ei=ZcJ9T7-sIqTg2AWl15WEDQ&usg=AFQjCNG0dAl5830guZoh8EfVVoveLlaNFA)

Comment: @DJP I also found that file. I was looking around for a public database with lots of pictures just like those in that file, but yet I found none

Comment: @Jake: have you used that plugin?  The code project is pretty stale and I never got it to work.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Yeah, it works fine for me. I haven't used it intensely, though.

Comment: see also http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf on how to use inkscape to convert svg to pdf and include it in a pdflatex file. works well!

Comment: @Werner: Yes, even from the command line `inkscape --export-pdf file.pdf file.svg`.

Answer (score 5):

Both TikZ and PStricks are used for creating images, rather than simply pasting them in. As such, you won't find clipart as such, but will find galleries of example images. For TikZ, you should look at [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) while for PStricks there are [2D](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery) and [3D](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D) galleries on the [PStricks website](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples).

Answer (score 4):

Look what I just found -

- `tikzpeople` by Nils Fleis­chhacker [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople?lang=en).
- `tikzducks` by sam­carter [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks?lang=en)
- Some related discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346695/how-can-we-draw-a-duck-in-order-to-create-a-tikzducks-package-and-store-it-in-c)

Making community wiki because these are not my work :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `texdoc pst-fun` or look at http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-fun/pst-fun-doc.pdf