# How can we draw a duck (in order to create a tikzducks package and store it in CTAN)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, tikzducks

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`tikzducks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks)

We have a `scsnowman` package but we don't have a `ducks` package, that's quite inexplicable since ducks are [frequently used on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=duck) (e.g., samcarter had to fall back on `\PHdove` of `phaistos` package [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344842/101651)).

I'm not an expert, nevertheless, I'd like to create a `tikzducks` package, similar to `tikzpeople`, but I need your help in order to create a customizable duck!

Requirements:

- I'd like to have a `duck`, not something a bit like it (ducks with a human body are NOT accepted)
- wings are mandatory
- from the look of the duck, it should appear cleary that it was
  created with LaTeX, not with other commercial tools.

Possible color-keys for the duck:

- body
- head
- wings
- eyes
- beak.

Possible optional add-ons:

- hat
- sport tools (e.g., cricket bat)
- male/female versions
- a seasonal version
- a Chinese version
- a cook version (not cooked version)
- a mathematician version.

As shown in Ulrike Fisher's answer, `tikzpeople` package has a beak feature but it doesn't allow to change the body of the image, so we get a person with a beak (quite ugly).

Loopspace pointed out that there is already a [`ducks` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/101651) but it doesn't allow to change the style of the duck (like `tikzpeople` does for people) and it is not yet present in CTAN.

Moreover, I'd like a style similar to this example of the seasonal version:

[image]

Go wild!

> P.S. = consider this question as if it has always a bounty open!

Comment: Don't forget the version: Cooking Ducks (no, not Cooking a duck ;-)) and  `Ducks solving Math problems` ;-)

Comment: Christian: saint now :-))))). I have voted the question.

Comment: Great question! There will be a huge demand for this! A great application would be automatically generate holiday appropriate avatars!

Comment: Doves are ducks, really? ;o)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Versions added.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Which question?

Comment: @Bernard Close enough for the purpose :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Very Good!

Comment: Why not the next US President, then?

Comment: @Bernard Doves are not ducks, that's why we need a `tikzducks` package! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Yet, you formulated \PHdove as an example of beloved duck on this site… ;o)

Comment: There is a `duck` package, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/86 (I have `\usepackage{duck}` in the preamble of one of my articles and use it as `\def\qedsymbol{\raisebox{-2pt}{\resizebox{1em}{!}{\drawduck}}}`)

Comment: @LoopSpace I can't find it in CTAN, where is its documentation?

Comment: @CarLaTeX It didn't make it to CTAN, sadly.  The only documentation that I know of is in that answer by the awesome Paulo Cereda.  There's a gist for the code (also linked in that answer).

Comment: @LoopSpace I don't know how CTAN works, why didn't it make to CTAN? Is it not enough demanded? Is it not enough serious? Didn't it pass the tests? (Actually I also don't find `snowmen` in CTAN, even if there was an announcement, here, some time ago).

Comment: @CarLaTeX I suspect that even Paulo thought that it was too frivolous for CTAN.  But don't tell him I said that!

Comment: The snowman package is call `scsnowman` (I have no idea what the sc is for -- perhaps "secret ctan").

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good news! If there is `scsnowman` I may ask a `ducks` package! I think they have the same level of frivolousness, hahaha! Thank you!

Comment: You can't forget the lame duck these days!

Comment: @CarLaTeX This sort of [lame duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lame_duck_(politics)) ;)

Comment: Why not a male version if there is to be a female version? Male birds are typically the more interesting to look at, given their tendency to favour fantastical displays in techni-colour glory.

Comment: This question really should be edited. This is not the appropriate place to request features from package authors, particularly authors of packages which already provide the features allegedly lacking.

Comment: @cfr I've thought of a female version because the male one is the standard version!

Comment: Why? What exactly about the standard version tells you he is male? I'm no expert on ducks, so it is not obvious to me.

Comment: Requests to package authors don't belong here. Obviously, you don't want to invalidate the existing answer, but you do want the question to reflect what you want. Including separate versions is just confusing, I think.

Comment: Can the package also handle duck-tape? :D

Comment: @ArneTimperman You're asking too much, let's try to get the static version first! Hahaha!

Comment: Yes, I think that is much clearer. Thank you :-). And surely we can safely ignore the many possible puns, such as that suggested by @ArneTimperman, and insist that candidates for inclusion really include `duck`and not something a bit like it?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that the wingless duck is any uglier than the armless humans. These all scream Microsoft to me .... (I don't know if this is fair or not, however.)

Comment: If there is to be a duck adorned with a flowery necklace, why not name it descriptively (`flowerduck`) rather than implying that flowers have the meaning 'female'? Semantic ideals of LaTeX and all that.

Comment: @dbmag9 Male/female versions are one of the requests, fell free to create a female version as you like and rename mine in `\flowerduck`. I'm waiting for (funny) answers! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Can you please post your code as an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Done! With some little improvements...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks! So everything is prepared for my philantropist hat :)

Comment: Your desiderata appear to be internally inconsistent. Ducks are not created by TeX but by other ducks. Hence, if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck-made duck. Or, at least, it must look like a duck-made duck. Hence, it cannot also be obviously created by LateX in a way which rules out commercial duck enterprises. (Or are you denying that ducks' entrepreneurial?) Also the examples given are all anthropomorphic, which seems to cohere less than perfectly with the duck-made duck requirement.

Comment: @cfr For the first point: http://lunpi.deviantart.com/art/Ceci-n-est-pas-une-pipe-91060034. For the second point: male/female ducks are not anthropomorphic... and do you deny that a duck could be a mathematician?  Or do you deny that there are ducks in China? Show us your answer!

Comment: Unless you want ducks disguised as cats, my ducks always use Paulo's code. So far, anyway.

Comment: @cfr Why not include Paulo's code in the package, in order to store it in CTAN?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Surely that's a question for Paulo?

Comment: @cfr Let's ask him...

Comment: @PauloCereda ^^^ Please give us your opinion! Ciao!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am the author of `scsnowman`; sc means "snowman commedian". Some TeXnicians in Japan are interested in the variety of snowman glyphs in Unicode fonts (I also described in the package documentatkon) and they are sometimes called "snowman enthusiasts" or "snowman comedians" (including me!).

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA Thank you for the explanation (and for the package)!

Comment: Now that we’ve finally got our `tikzducks` package, the question arises as to whether we should also have a `mathduck` package, to use ducks as math symbols too.  I think it should be relatively easy to build it on the top of the code of the `halloweenmath` package… ;-)

Comment: @GuM Yay! But it's not necessary to create a _new_ package, you could change the `halloweenmath` and add it! :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Ducks are not creepy: ducks are cute! :-)

Comment: @GuM I'm waiting for the `mathduck` package, then! :):):)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

> No new ducks will be added to the question, instead this project moved on to become a latex package. Please visit the project repository at https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks or have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks if you want to see new ducks :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage[paperwidth=38cm,paperheight=42cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{bbding}

\newcommand{\duck}[1]{%

    \colorlet{duck}{#1}
    \colorlet{eye}{Cornsilk}
    \colorlet{pupil}{black}
    \colorlet{bill}{orange}

    %body
    \path[fill=duck] (51.2815,135.5394) .. controls (26.6859,139.7884) and (-12.5215,184.2616) .. (28.9411,223.8858) .. controls (70.4036,263.5099) and (286.2675,236.9673) .. (181.7701,108.1215) .. controls (93.7517,155.4266) and (123.9624,112.1537) .. (51.2815,135.5394) -- cycle;

    %head
    \path[fill=duck] (90,100) ellipse (1.4cm and 1.75cm);

    % duck's bill
    \path[fill=bill, xshift=-11pt, xscale=1.1] (49.3866,102.7929) .. controls (70.9472,97.0244) and (61.6632,119.6616) .. (95.1826,113) .. controls (20,165) and (36.9082,113.0997) .. (49.3866,102.7929) -- cycle;

    % right eye
    \path[fill=eye, rotate=20, xshift=-4pt, yshift=1pt] (112,58) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.35cm);
    \path[fill=pupil, rotate=20, xshift=-4pt, yshift=1pt] (115,59) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.2cm);

    % left eye
    \path[fill=eye, rotate=20] (78,62) ellipse (0.22cm and 0.32cm);
    \path[fill=pupil, rotate=20] (81,63) ellipse (0.08cm and 0.18cm);

}

\newcommand{\grumpyduck}[1]{%

    \colorlet{duck}{#1}
    \colorlet{eye}{Cornsilk}
    \colorlet{pupil}{black}
    \colorlet{bill}{orange}

    %body
    \path[fill=duck] (51.2815,135.5394) .. controls (26.6859,139.7884) and (-12.5215,184.2616) .. (28.9411,223.8858) .. controls (70.4036,263.5099) and (286.2675,236.9673) .. (181.7701,108.1215) .. controls (93.7517,155.4266) and (123.9624,112.1537) .. (51.2815,135.5394) -- cycle;

    %head
    \path[fill=duck] (90,100) ellipse (1.4cm and 1.75cm);

    % duck's bill
    \path[fill=bill, xshift=-11pt, xscale=1.1] (49.3866,102.7929) .. controls (70.9472,97.0244) and (70.9472,97.0244) .. (85.1826,120) .. controls (20,165) and (36.9082,113.0997) .. (49.3866,102.7929) -- cycle;

    % right eye
    \path[fill=eye, rotate=20, xshift=-4pt, yshift=1pt] (112,58) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.35cm);
    \path[fill=pupil, rotate=20, xshift=-4pt, yshift=1pt] (115,59) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.2cm);

    % left eye
    \path[fill=eye, rotate=20] (78,62) ellipse (0.22cm and 0.32cm);
    \path[fill=pupil, rotate=20] (81,63) ellipse (0.08cm and 0.18cm);

}

\newcommand{\addalien}{%
    \draw[line width=3pt,color=YellowGreen] (110,62) -- (130,20);
    \draw[line width=3pt,color=YellowGreen] (72,58) -- (60,15);
    \path[fill=YellowGreen] (130,20) circle (0.2cm);
    \path[fill=YellowGreen] (60,15) circle (0.2cm);
}

\newcommand{\addhat}[1]{%
    \path[fill=#1] (90,55) ellipse (1.3cm and 0.25cm);
    \path[fill=#1] (90,30) ellipse (0.7cm and 0.2cm);
    \path[fill=#1] (115,30) rectangle (65,55);
}

\newcommand{\addsunglasses}{
    \draw[line width=3pt,color=black] (48,95) arc (190:370:20) ;
    \path[draw=black,line width=3pt] (95,90) -- (130,100);
    \path[fill=black, rotate=20] (111,58) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.4cm);
    \path[fill=black, rotate=20] (80,60) ellipse (0.37cm and 0.37cm);
}

\newcommand{\addglasses}[1]{
    \draw[line width=2pt,color=#1] (62,80) arc (267:297:20) ;
    \path[draw=#1,line width=2pt] (93,88) -- (130,100);
    \path[draw=#1,line width=2pt, rotate=20] (107,58) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.35cm);
    \path[draw=#1,line width=2pt, rotate=20] (78,61) ellipse (0.32cm and 0.32cm);
}

\newcommand{\addicecream}[3]{
    \path[draw=Sienna,fill=Goldenrod,line width=1pt,yshift=50pt,rotate=20,xshift=50pt] 
    (45,60)--(60,120)--(75,60);
    \path[draw=Sienna, fill=Goldenrod, rotate=20,line width=1pt] (144,118) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \path[fill=#1, rotate=20] (138,116) circle (0.3cm);
    \path[fill=#2, rotate=20] (148,116) circle (0.3cm);
    \path[fill=#3, rotate=20] (142,102) circle (0.3cm);
}

\newcommand{\addunicorn}{
    \path[draw=VioletRed,fill=Pink,line width=1pt,yshift=20pt,rotate=-25,xshift=0pt] 
    (50,60)--(60,20)--(70,60);
}

\newcommand{\addhair}[1]{%
    \path[fill=#1, xshift=-5pt] (151.3277,174.3473) .. controls (157.7099,171.1213) and (164.7938,167.8644) .. (168.7230,161.6896) .. controls (164.8427,161.5316) and (153.5102,155.4255) .. (162.1164,152.9395) .. controls (169.4207,153.1460) and (176.4092,149.5358) .. (179.3920,142.6587) .. controls (185.5577,133.4026) and (172.4051,138.2448) .. (169.0163,134.3455) .. controls (174.7801,132.5948) and (184.6532,131.7138) .. (187.4798,127.5635) .. controls (176.4675,125.1191) and (163.1258,123.3733) .. (156.8817,112.6068) .. controls (152.4387,98.5734) and (153.2098,83.5059) .. (149.6492,69.2411) .. controls (131.4926,-1.1678) and (29.6020,22.0627) .. (47.7294,90.0940) .. controls (49.6639,62.0732) and (72.5401,38.6998) .. (96.3583,54.2220) .. controls (130.5162,76.1752) and (139.7469,117.8581) .. (115.3043,143.8986) .. controls (115.2213,148.9109) and (117.2762,158.3403) .. (124.2981,163.2993) .. controls (131.3200,168.2584) and (141.2814,171.4676) .. (151.3277,174.3473) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\addshirt}[1]{%
    \path[fill=#1] (50,135.5394) .. controls (26.6859,139.7884) and (-12.5215,184.2616) .. (28.9411,223.8858) .. controls (70.4036,263.5099) and (286.2675,236.9673) .. (181.7701,108.1215) .. controls (93.7517,155.4266) and (123.9624,112.1537) .. (51.2815,180) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\addtie}[1]{
    \draw[line width=10pt,color=#1] (60,150) -- (50,190);
}

\newcommand{\addtshirt}[1]{
    \path[fill=#1] (50,135.5394) .. controls (26.6859,139.7884) and (-12.5215,184.2616) .. (28.9411,223.8858) .. controls (70.4036,263.5099) and (286.2675,236.9673) .. (181.7701,108.1215) .. controls (93.7517,155.4266) and (123.9624,122.1537) .. (59,150) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\addshorthair}[1]{
    \path[fill=#1, xshift=-5pt] (145.7190,108.2466) .. controls (151.7052,104.8240) and (153.2448,84.3447) .. (149.6842,70.0799) .. controls (131.5276,-0.3291) and (29.6371,22.9015) .. (47.7644,90.9328) .. controls (49.6989,62.9120) and (80.4610,40.0060) .. (101.1924,59.4599) .. controls (128.6626,85.2375) and (139.4074,111.8552) .. (145.7190,108.2466) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\addwizzard}{
    \path[fill=BlueViolet!50!Pink,line width=1pt,yshift=-40pt,rotate=5,xshift=32pt] 
    (20,100)--(60,0)--(100,100);
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{71}{-15}, left, base]{\color{Gold}\EightStarBold}
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{63}{0}, left, base]{\color{Gold}\EightStarBold~\EightStarBold}
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{56}{15}, left, base]{\color{Gold}\EightStarBold~\EightStarBold~\EightStarBold}
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{56}{30}, left, base]{\color{Gold}\EightStarBold~\EightStarBold~\EightStarBold}
    \draw[line width=6pt,color=black] (90,160) -- (60,210);
    \draw[line width=6pt,color=white] (85,168.333) -- (80,176.666);
}

\newcommand{\makeeinstein}[1]{
    \path[fill=#1,xshift=-4pt] (24.7738,59.7679) .. controls (31.3318,44.0108) and (53.1939,44.5256) .. (52.1285,41.2094) .. controls (51.4718,28.9400) and (30.1562,26.0780) .. (30.1562,26.0780) .. controls (48.5184,20.6686) and (79.2723,56.9617) .. (62.4298,11.1490) .. controls (65.1702,13.6709) and (88.0663,32.6096) .. (85.8201,7.5499) .. controls (87.7073,21.1456) and (96.9496,45.9959) .. (104.3286,23.2724) .. controls (113.1425,-15.9325) and (101.8773,49.6572) .. (138.4988,13.8484) .. controls (141.5713,17.0755) and (121.2714,39.5689) .. (139.2365,36.1290) .. controls (136.0271,66.8833) and (155.4874,23.7659) .. (155.4874,23.7659) .. controls (155.4874,23.7659) and (151.7518,45.0675) .. (147.8705,54.3986) .. controls (147.8705,54.3986) and (173.2987,55.3029) .. (176.7812,61.7670) .. controls (124.2612,69.4624) and (206.6010,77.2343) .. (154.2298,77.2507) .. controls (158.6628,83.1536) and (135.1295,89.9115) .. (169.9992,90.5427) .. controls (93.3592,92.0258) and (132.6373,57.7941) .. (94.5654,45.5826) .. controls (60.1628,40.4228) and (57.2813,64.7295) .. (51.9497,70.3679) .. controls (53.2460,53.9344) and (41.0100,59.0530) .. (24.7738,59.7679) -- cycle;

    \draw[line width=5pt,color=#1,line cap=round] (96,80) -- (82,73);
    \draw[line width=5pt,color=#1,line cap=round] (50,69) -- (60,68);

}

\newcommand{\addbook}[2]{
        \path[fill=#1,rotate=20] (110,120) rectangle (150,180);
        \node[rotate=-20, color=white] at (73,180)  {\makebox[2cm][c]{#2}};
}

\newcommand{\addwater}[1]{
    \draw [decorate,decoration=snake, line width=3pt, color=#1] (0,200) -- (100,200);
    \draw [decorate,decoration=snake, line width=3pt, color=#1] (180,200) -- (220,200);
    \draw [decorate,decoration=snake, line width=3pt, color=#1] (50,210) -- (150,210);
    \draw [decorate,decoration=snake, line width=3pt, color=#1] (110,230) -- (250,230);
    \draw [decorate,decoration=snake, line width=3pt, color=#1] (20,240) -- (70,240);
    \draw [decorate,decoration=snake, line width=3pt, color=#1] (60,250) -- (250,250);
}


\begin{document}

% grumpy
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \grumpyduck{Gold}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%Christian Hupfer
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addwizzard
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% short hairs
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Wheat}
    \addtshirt{LightBlue!50!white}
    \addshirt{LightSlateGrey}
    \addshorthair{brown!50!Grey}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%Men in black
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \grumpyduck{Wheat}
    \addtshirt{white}
    \addshirt{black}
    \addtie{black}
    \addhat{black}
    \addsunglasses
\end{tikzpicture}
%

% ducklings
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-0.6, xscale=0.6, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=300pt, scale=.3, yshift=400pt]
        \duck{Gold}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=180pt, scale=.3, yshift=350pt]
        \duck{Gold}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=240pt, scale=.3, yshift=450pt]
        \duck{Gold}
    \end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% samcarter
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Wheat!95!red}
    \addshirt{MidnightBlue}
    \addhair{OrangeRed!50!Brown}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% hair
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addhair{SeaGreen}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% unicorn
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Pink}
    \addhair{MediumVioletRed}
    \addunicorn
\end{tikzpicture}

% icecream
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addicecream{Wheat}{Plum}{Chocolate}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% sunglasses
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addsunglasses
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% normal duck
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
\end{tikzpicture}
% blue duck
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{SteelBlue}
\end{tikzpicture}

% alien duck
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addalien
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% hat duck
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addhat{SaddleBrown}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% swimming
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold}
    \addwater{blue!50!cyan} 
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% Brazil colour duck for Paulo
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \definecolor{brazilgreen}{RGB}{0,155,58}
    \definecolor{brazilyellow}{RGB}{254,223,0}
    \definecolor{brazilblue}{RGB}{0,39,118}
    \duck{brazilyellow}
    \addshirt{brazilblue}
    \addshorthair{brazilgreen}
\end{tikzpicture}

% prof. van duck
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \duck{Gold!40!white}
    \makeeinstein{gray!50!white}
    \addglasses{brown!70!black}
    \addbook{brown!70!black}{\TeX}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: damn awesome! :D

Comment: I'd somehow failed to vote for this until now!

Comment: You're currently 22 ducks short of your promise!

Comment: @JPi Only one, as the "New rule" does not apply for old votes :) However its hard to keep the pace ...

Comment: @CarLaTeX The unicorn got some hair :)

Comment: You can join efforts with  Nils Fleis­chhacker (`tikzpeople` author) and create a new `tikzducks` package :)

Comment: I'd leave out the hat of the _duck in black_ https://youtu.be/fiBLgEx6svA or change the shape of the hat if it's a _blues brother duck_ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blues_Brothers (please note Donald "Duck" Dunn – bass guitar) :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Guess I should learn how to write a package over the summer break :)

Comment: @samcarter Yay!

Comment: Gimme 100 ducks because of the bounty! `:D`

Comment: @PauloCereda Thank you very much for the bounty :) You forgot to take into account the conversion factor between points and votes - so don't expect more than 10 :) This may need a bit of time, but the first one will be the Brazilian coloured duck to honour your bounty - I bet it will get along nicely with the wizard themed one for Christian Hupfer :) And then I was thinking maybe superhero themed ducks? And of course grumpy duck will be back.

Comment: @PauloCereda Unfortunately not yet ten, but three new ducks, including grumpy duck :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I added Prof. van Duck

Comment: @samcarter Gorgeous!!! <3 <3 <3

Comment: @PauloCereda ^^^

Comment: @CarLaTeX The Professor looks a bit different than his usual self, but white on white background was too boring so he decided to get a bit of suntan on the beach first :)

Comment: @samcarter we've just came back from holidays (see my photos in chat) :):):)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you are working hard to write the package!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks! One last problem with the eye brows, finishing the documentation and it should be ready to publish :)

Comment: I'm looking forward to using it :):):) Thank you!

Comment: @samcarter we can see you hiding yourself among ducks. Lol. Excellent work.

Comment: I was learning TikZ so I could write a book on linear algebra. Now, with tikzducks, I need to use these ducks somewhere. But where??? I need to use this!!! Help!!!

Comment: @AndréCaldas Oh, I can understand this problem! The only scientific usage for the tikzducks I found so far is an explanation of the Cherenkov effect. In case you find a good usage, please consider adding an answer!

Comment: @AndréCaldas For an application of the ducks in mathematics, see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42142547#42142547

Comment: please undelete that titlesec answer from half an hour ago. It is perfectly fine :-)

Comment: But, sam, I am lazy, i don't want to answer.

Answer (score 58):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[duck,evil,minimum size=1.5cm] (B){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without code ...

[image]

Comment: tikzpeople don't have hands or wings (but  can hold a sword and a shield)

Comment: Why the horns?  Is it a devil duck?

Comment: @CarLaTeX The point is: the package already provides ducks. The question should take account of this: how can the package be used to create a duck? Or how can we draw a duck, given that the packages available to draw ducks are all lacking in some way? Or whatever.

Comment: never seen a duck with line up haircut. :)

Comment: @jamesqf see the code or the documentation of tikzpeople.

Comment: @jamesqf  It is not a devil duck, but a viking duck. The code is not over until the fat duck sings.  For comparable memes with other animals, google "viking kitty".

Answer (score 40):

Here is what I have done till now (to be improved, of course).

[image]

This is my `tikzducks.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{tikzducks}[2016/01/05 All we need is\dots ducks!]

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,decorations.markings}

\RequirePackage{halloweenmath}

\tikzset{%
    pics/wing/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) to[bend right] (1,0) to[bend left] (.7,-.6) to[bend left] cycle;
    }}, 
    pics/eye/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=white] (-.1,-.05) ellipse (.3 and .2);
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle[radius=.1];
    }},
    pics/paw/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=orange] (0,0) -- (0,.8) -- (.1,.8) -- (.1,.05) -- (.8,.05) to[bend right] (.7,-.2) to[bend right] (.6,-.45) -- cycle;
    }},
    pics/body/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) to[bend right] (.6,-1.2) to[bend right] (2,-2.4) to[bend right=70, smooth] (3.7,-.1) to[bend left] cycle;
    }},
    pics/head/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle[radius=.9];
    }},
    pics/closedbeak/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=orange] (0,0) -- (-.35,.1) -- (-.65,-.3) -- (-.1,-.7) to[bend right=70] (.2,-.5) -- cycle;
    }},
    pics/openbeak/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=orange] (0,0) -- (.5,.35) to[bend left=70] (.55,.25) -- (.23,-.29) -- (.3,-.7) to[bend left=70] (.25,-.75) -- (-.01,-.45) -- cycle;
    }},
    create duck coordinates/.style = {insert path={(0,0) coordinate (duck)}},
    pics/duck/.style={code={%
        \pic[rotate=30] at (.5,-1.8) {paw};
        \pic at (-2.5,1) {body};
        \pic at (-1,0) {wing};
        \pic at (1.5,1) {head};
        \pic at (2.2,.8) {closedbeak};
        \pic[rotate=300] at (1.6,.9) {eye};
        \pic[xscale=1,yscale=-1,rotate=75] at (1.91,1.08) {eye};
        \path (-1,-1.8) coordinate (paw);
        \pic[rotate=330] at (paw) {paw};
    }},
    create duckwithopenbeak coordinates/.style = {insert path={(0,0) coordinate (duckwithopenbeak)}},
    pics/duckwithopenbeak/.style={code={%
        \pic[rotate=30] at (.5,-1.8) {paw};
        \pic at (-2.5,1) {body};
        \pic at (-1,0) {wing};
        \pic at (1.5,1) {head};
        \pic[rotate=300] at (1.94,1.06) {eye};
        \pic[rotate=-20] at (2.4,.9) {openbeak};
        \path (-1,-1.8) coordinate (paw);
        \pic[rotate=330] at (paw) {paw};
    }},
    create bow coordinates/.style = {insert path={(1.3,1.8) coordinate (bow)}},
    pics/bow/.style={code={%
        \draw[red, fill=pink, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (.7,.55) -- (.7,-.55) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=pink, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (-.7,.55) -- (-.7,-.55) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=pink] (0,0) circle [radius=1/4];
    }},
    pics/daisy/.style={code={%
        \foreach \i in {0,45,...,325}
            \draw[blue, fill=white, rotate=\i]
                (0,0) .. controls ++(-30:1/2) and ++(30:1/2) .. cycle;
            \draw[orange, fill=yellow] circle [radius=1/8];
    }},
    create nacklace coordinates/.style = {insert path={(.6,.7) coordinate (nacklace)}},
    pics/nacklace/.style={code={%
        \path (0,0) coordinate (nacklacebase);
        \pic at (nacklacebase) {daisy};
        \pic[below right=1em and 1em of nacklacebase] {daisy};
        \pic[below right=2em and 2em of nacklacebase] {daisy};
    }},
    create blackboard coordinates/.style = {insert path={(3.5,1.8) coordinate (blackboard)}},
    pics/blackboard/.style={code={%
        \node at (0,0) [rectangle, fill=black, draw=brown, very thick,font={\color{white}\bfseries\small},minimum height=10ex] {$ax^2+bx+c=0$};
    }},
    create glasses coordinates/.style = {insert path={(1.5,.8) coordinate (glasses)}},
    pics/glasses/.style={code={%
        \node [circle, draw=blue, very thick,minimum height=1.1em] (rglass) {};
        \node[right=.5em of rglass, circle, draw=blue, very thick,minimum height=1.1em] (lglass) {};
        \coordinate[above left=.1em and .9em of rglass] (rrglass);
        \coordinate[below left=.5em and .1em of rrglass] (rrrglass);
        \coordinate[above right=.1em and .9em of lglass] (llglass);
        \coordinate[below right=.5em and .1em of llglass] (lllglass);
        \draw[draw=blue, very thick] (rglass) -- (lglass);
        \draw[draw=blue, very thick] (rglass) -- (rrglass) -- (rrrglass);
        \draw[draw=blue, very thick] (lglass) -- (llglass) -- (lllglass);
    }},
    create soccerball coordinates/.style = {insert path={(2.6,-1.1) coordinate (soccerball)}},
    pics/soccerball/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=.9];
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle [radius=.9];
            \foreach \i in {-.4,.4}
            \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill=black,minimum height=3.5ex] at (\i,.4) {};
            \foreach \i in {-.8,0,.8} 
            \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill=black,minimum height=3.5ex] at (\i,-.4) {};
        \end{scope}
    }},
    create befana coordinates/.style = {insert path={(0,0) coordinate (befana)}},
    pics/befana/.style={code={%
        \node {$\displaystyle\mathwitch$};
    }},
    create ghost coordinates/.style = {insert path={(-.8,-.12) coordinate (ghost)}},
    pics/ghost/.style={code={%
        \node {$\xrightswishingghost{\mspace{30mu}}$};
    }},
    create help coordinates/.style = {insert path={(4.6,2.3) coordinate (help)}},
    pics/help/.style={code={%
        \node[draw, fill=white, shape=starburst, text width=5.7em, text centered] (helpnode) {%
                Help! \\ A \texttt{\textbackslash phantom}!
            };
        \coordinate[below left=-.1em and -0.3em of helpnode] (lhelpnode);
        \coordinate[below right=0.35em and -1.5em of helpnode] (rhelpnode);
        \coordinate[below left=2.3em and 1.1em of helpnode] (bhelpnode);
        \coordinate[below left=-.3em and -0.4em of helpnode] (llhelpnode);
        \coordinate[below right=0em and -.9em of helpnode] (rrhelpnode);
        \path[fill=white] (llhelpnode) -- (bhelpnode) -- (rrhelpnode);  
        \draw[fill=white] (lhelpnode) -- (bhelpnode) -- (rhelpnode);
    }},
    create righttooth coordinates/.style = {insert path={(2.11,.1) coordinate (righttooth)}},
    create lefttooth coordinates/.style = {insert path={(2.29,.15) coordinate (lefttooth)}},
    pics/tooth/.style={code={%
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0) -- (.05,-.2) -- (.11,.1);
    }},
    create cloak coordinates/.style = {insert path={(.65,.69) coordinate (cloak)}},
    pics/cloak/.style={code={%
        \draw[white,fill=black] (0,0) to[bend left=10] (-2.1,.1) 
            decorate [decoration={snake, segment length=10pt, amplitude=3pt}] 
            {to  (-2,-1.4)}   to[bend left=9]  (.3,-.4)  to[bend left=30] cycle;
        \draw[white,fill=black] (0,0) to[bend left=10] (-.1,.7) to[bend right=15] (.7,-.3) -- (.3,-.4) to[bend left=30] cycle;
    }},
    pics/batflock/.style={code={%
    \path[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.01 with {\node[scale=0.4,rotate=-50] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.04 with {\node[scale=0.5,rotate=-40] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.07 with {\node[scale=0.6,rotate=-35] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.11 with {\node[scale=0.7,rotate=-30] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.15 with {\node[scale=0.8,rotate=-20] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.20 with {\node[scale=0.9,rotate=-10] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.25 with {\node[scale=1.0,rotate=5] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.31 with {\node[scale=1.1,rotate=15] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.38 with {\node[scale=1.2,rotate=15] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.44 with {\node[scale=1.3,rotate=0] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.50 with {\node[scale=1.4,rotate=-15] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.57 with {\node[scale=1.5,rotate=-25] {$\mathbat$};},
            mark=at position 0.65 with {\node[scale=1.6,rotate=-30] {$\mathbat$};}, 
            mark=at position 0.73 with {\node[scale=1.7,rotate=-35] {$\mathbat$};}, 
            mark=at position 0.81 with {\node[scale=1.8,rotate=-40] {$\mathbat$};},     
            mark=at position 0.89 with {\node[scale=1.9,rotate=-42] {$\mathbat$};},     
        }}] plot[smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (2.5,1) (1,3) (7,4.5)};
    \path[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.01 with {\node[scale=0.4,rotate=10] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.06 with {\node[scale=0.5,rotate=10] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.11 with {\node[scale=0.6,rotate=10] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.17 with {\node[scale=0.7,rotate=10] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.23 with {\node[scale=0.8,rotate=5] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.30 with {\node[scale=0.9,rotate=0] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.38 with {\node[scale=1.0,rotate=-10] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.48 with {\node[scale=1.1,rotate=-20] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.58 with {\node[scale=1.2,rotate=-30] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.68 with {\node[scale=1.3,rotate=-40] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.79 with {\node[scale=1.4,rotate=-41] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.90 with {\node[scale=1.5,rotate=-42] {$\xleftflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
        }}] plot[smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(1.7,1.3) (0,2.7) (2,4.5) (5,5.5)};
    \path[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.16 with {\node[scale=0.4,rotate=-5] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.25 with {\node[scale=0.5,rotate=-25] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.34 with {\node[scale=0.6,rotate=-36] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.44 with {\node[scale=0.7,rotate=-38] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.55 with {\node[scale=0.8,rotate=-40] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.67 with {\node[scale=0.9,rotate=-42] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.81 with {\node[scale=1.0,rotate=-46] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
            mark=at position 0.95 with {\node[scale=1.1,rotate=-50] {$\xrightflutteringbat{\mspace{30mu}}$};},
        }}] plot[smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(2.5,2) (2,2.7) (6.5,3.3)};
    }},
}

\newcommand{\duck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic {duck};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\daisyduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic {duck};
        \path[create nacklace coordinates];
        \pic at (nacklace) {nacklace};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\femaleduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic {duck};
        \path[create bow coordinates];
        \pic[rotate=35] at (bow) {bow}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\mathduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[create blackboard coordinates];
        \pic at (blackboard) {blackboard};
        \pic {duck};
        \path[create glasses coordinates];
        \pic[rotate=30, transform shape] at (glasses) {glasses};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\soccerduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic {duck};
        \path[create soccerball coordinates];
        \pic[rotate=30] at (soccerball) {soccerball};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\befanaduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box] (-2.5,-1.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);  
        \pic[scale=.45,transform canvas={scale=.45},transform shape,rotate=20] at (3.17,1.59) {duck};
        \path[create befana coordinates];
        \pic[transform canvas={scale=4}] at (befana) {befana};
        \pic[rotate=330,scale=.45,transform canvas={scale=.45},transform shape,rotate=20] at (paw) {paw};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\ghostduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box] (-6,-2.5) rectangle (6,2.5);  
        \path[create ghost coordinates];
        \pic[transform canvas={scale=7}] at (ghost) {ghost};
        \pic {duckwithopenbeak};
        \path[create help coordinates];
        \pic at (help) {help};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\vampireduck}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic at (-6,-1) {batflock};
        \path[create righttooth coordinates];
        \pic at (righttooth) {tooth};
        \path[create lefttooth coordinates];
        \pic at (lefttooth) {tooth};
        \pic {duck};
        \path[create cloak coordinates];
        \pic at (cloak) {cloak};
        \pic at (-1,0) {wing};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This is the code of the presentation:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: convert: {density: 160, otheroptions: -dispose previous -delay 140 -loop 1, format: gif}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\cprotect\title{Quack guide to \verb|tikzducks| package}
\subtitle{Actually, some examples to be improved and transformed into a package}
\author{Car\LaTeX}
\institute{Duck fan club}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{Standard version}
    Command: 
    \begin{center}
        \verb|\duck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \duck   
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{Female version}
    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\femaleduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \femaleduck
    \end{figure}
    Accessory \verb|pic| available: \verb|bow| 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=.7, transform canvas={scale=.7}] at (.6,.2) {bow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{Daisy version}
    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\daisyduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \daisyduck
    \end{figure}
    Accessory \verb|pic|s available: \verb|daisy| 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=.75, transform canvas={scale=.75}] at (.35,.25) {daisy};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \hspace{1em} and \verb|nacklace| 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=.5, transform canvas={scale=.5}] at (.5,1) {nacklace};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{Mathematician version}
    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\mathduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \mathduck
    \end{figure}
    Accessory \verb|pic|s available:
    \verb|glasses| 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=.5, transform canvas={scale=.5}] at (.7,.2) {glasses};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{2.4em} and \verb|blackboard| 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=.4, transform canvas={scale=.4}] at (1.4,.5) {blackboard};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{Soccer player version}
    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\soccerduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \soccerduck
    \end{figure}
    Accessory \verb|pic| available: \verb|soccerball| 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=.5,transform canvas={scale=.5},transform shape] at (.5,.3) {soccerball};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\ 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{The Befana duck\dots}
    Using \verb|\displaystyle\mathwitch| $\displaystyle\mathwitch$ from the gorgeous Gustavo Mezzetti's package \verb|halloweenmath|, here is the Befana\footnote{For anyone who doesn't know who the Befana is, she's a sort of female version of Santa Claus, who brings gifts or coal (to good and bad children, respectively) every year on January, 6\textsuperscript{th}.} duck!

    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\befanaduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \befanaduck
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{\dots the ghost duck\dots}
    Using \verb|\xrightswishingghost| $\xrightswishingghost{}$, again from \verb|halloweenmath| package, here is the ghost duck!\\
    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\ghostduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{%
    \ghostduck
    }
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \frametitle{\dots and the vampire duck!}
    The vampire duck, with bats from \verb|halloweenmath| package!

    Command: 
    \begin{center}
    \verb|\vampireduck|
    \end{center}
    Result:
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
    \vampireduck
    }
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1!  But I cannot see the rationale for including (or even just for considering inclusion of) the `halloweenmath` package…

Comment: Do you know [Room on the Broom (kids' book)](http://roomonthebroom.com/)? he duck sits just where the cat does in the illustrations. *The witch had a duck and...* I wonder what a good rhyme would be

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't know that kids' book, but in the `halloweenmath` package there is a black cat on the broom, let's see if someone can find a good rhyme! Hahaha

Comment: Really lovely! (:-)  But why not `\node {$\displaystyle\mathwitch$}`?

Comment: I think that just the beard is worth it! :-)  And now that you are at it, what about a duck pursued by a ghost?  :o)

Comment: Very nice!  In the meanwhile, bats are going to been added to the `halloweenmath` package… :-)

Comment: Returning to the ghost, note that you can adjust the length of the swish by saying something like `\xrightswishingghost{\mspace{100mu}}` (may be that `100mu` is too much, anyway…).

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Truly suited to a vampire duck!  BTW, you could replace `\xleftflutteringbat{...}` (resp., `\xrightflutteringbat{...}`) with `\mathleftbat` (resp., `\mathrightbat`): it simply depends on whether you want the “swishes” or not.

Answer (score 13):

Since David Carlisle is too shy to add his solutions here, I've copied them from chat for him and added as community wiki.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
    Football duck:

    \begin{picture}(100,100)
    \put(50,50){\oval(50,20){}}
    \put(70,65){\circle{20}}
    \put(35,50){\line(1,0){30}}
    \put(70,65){\circle*{2}}
    \put(75,67){\line(6,-1){10}}
    \put(75,63){\line(6,1){10}}
    {\thicklines\multiput(30,40)(9,0){5}{\line(0,1){17}}}%
    \put(70,42){\circle*{10}}
    \end{picture}

    Pineapple pizza duck dedicated to me:   

    \begin{picture}(100,100)
    \put(50,50){\oval(50,20){}}
    \put(70,65){\circle{20}}
    \put(35,50){\line(1,0){30}}
    \put(70,65){\circle*{2}}
    \put(75,67){\line(6,-1){10}}
    \put(75,63){\line(6,1){10}}
    \put(70,42){{\color[RGB]{230,230,200}\circle*{40}}}
    \put(70,42){{\color{yellow}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(65,38){{\color{yellow}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(66,42){{\color{yellow}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(72,36){{\color{yellow}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(75,42){{\color{yellow}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(72,46){{\color{yellow}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(69,43){{\color[RGB]{255,128,64}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(65,36){{\color[RGB]{255,128,64}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(62,40){{\color[RGB]{255,128,64}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(69,40){{\color[RGB]{255,128,64}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(71,38){{\color[RGB]{255,128,64}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \put(66,45){{\color[RGB]{255,128,64}\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}
    \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm too shy, it says so above.

Answer (score 8):

> > *I'm pretty sure that somebody is going to complain that this answer is insufficiently serious and unworthy of this site's lofty aims. To the critics say I, you clearly spend too little time mucking about in the river.*

True love with a soul mate ...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcounter{duckno}
\tikzset{
  hwyaden/.pic={
    \tikzset{hwyaden/.cd, shading/.style={#1}}
    \stepcounter{duckno}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box/.expanded=h\theduckno]
      \shade [hwyaden/shading] (0,0) -- (-\mathhwyaden,0) -- (120:{6*\mathhwyaden}) arc (120:60:{6*\mathhwyaden}) -- (\mathhwyaden,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \clip ([yshift={-4*\mathhwyaden},xshift={-2*\mathhwyaden}]h\theduckno.south west) coordinate (a) rectangle ([yshift={6*\mathhwyaden}, xshift={2*\mathhwyaden}]h\theduckno.east |- a) coordinate (e);
    \shade [top color=blue!50!cyan, bottom color=blue!75!black!25, middle color=blue!50!black, decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt, segment length=\mathhwyaden}] ([xshift=\mathhwyaden, yshift=-\mathhwyaden]e) -|  ([xshift=-\mathhwyaden, yshift=-\mathhwyaden]a) -| cycle;
  },
  hwyaden/.search also={/tikz/},
  hwyaden/.cd,
  shading/.style=black,
  size/.store in=\mathhwyaden,
  size=10pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {hwyaden={ball color=brown, postaction={outer color=Brown, inner color=Apricot, opacity=.5}}};
  \pic at (60pt,0) {hwyaden={preaction={outer color=DarkGreen, inner color=ForestGreen, opacity=1}, ball color=LimeGreen, opacity=.75, postaction={outer color=DarkGreen, inner color=Gold, opacity=.75}}};
  \node (d) [anchor=mid west, white, font=\itshape\bfseries, align=left] at ([yshift={-5*\mathhwyaden}]h1.west) {Heads down, tails up,\\Dabbling free!};
  \node [white, anchor=north east, font=\footnotesize\itshape] at (d.south -| current bounding box.east) {--- Kenneth Grahame};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A duck with her drake ...

[image: duck & drake]

Comment: https://www.google.it/amp/s/gurglewords.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/ducks-ditty-kenneth-grahame-plus-the-mysteries-of-rustling-in-the-rushes/amp/ I've just learnt that Prof. van Duck is a _drake_ O.o

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's not the link I used, but I saw `gurglewords` among my search results. Incidentally, this pair each have wings although, of course, they are under water at the moment.

Comment: I'd put the large part of the tail near the water and the tip up: https://youtu.be/dRRhwOp89F8

Comment: @CarLaTeX My duck and her drake aspire to be peacocks.

Comment: oooh two ducks!

Comment: No German could dispute this solution, as this is deeply imprinted by one of the most famous children's songs https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alle_meine_Entchen#Melodie  (translation: http://angelikasgerman.co.uk/alle-meine-entchen/)

Comment: hwyaden gynffon-hir?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer :-)

Comment: @PauloCereda Dwy hwyaden ;).

Comment: @samcarter So with *Wind in the Willows* and *Alle meine Entchen* together, I have the English- and German-speaking worlds covered ;).

Answer (score 8):

## <del>TikZ</del>Picducks

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1.5cm}
\begin{picture}(4.2,4.5)
\thicklines%

% bill
\qbezier(0.65,2.95)(-0.1,1.75)(1.68,2.73)
\qbezier(0.65,2.95)(0.9,3.05)(1.14,2.80)
\qbezier(1.14,2.80)(1.35,2.65)(1.68,2.73)

% head
\qbezier(0.65,2.95)(0.6,4.15)(1.68,4.24)
\qbezier(1.68,4.24)(2.9,4.1)(2.53,2.4)

% body
\qbezier(0.8,2.32)(-0.6,1.1)(0.8,0.3)
\qbezier(0.8,0.3)(2,-0.1)(3.5,0.65)
\qbezier(3.5,0.65)(4.6,1.5)(3.5,2.83)
\qbezier(3.5,2.83)(3,2.5)(2.53,2.4)

% right eye
\qbezier(1.3,3.2)(1.38,3.45)(1.6,3.4)
\qbezier(1.6,3.4)(1.73,3.3)(1.67,3.1)
\qbezier(1.67,3.1)(1.6,2.9)(1.45,2.93)
\qbezier(1.45,2.93)(1.27,2.95)(1.3,3.2)
\put(1.53,3.13){\circle*{0.17}}

% left eye -0.53, +0.12
\qbezier(0.77,3.32)(0.84,3.57)(1.03,3.5)
\qbezier(1.03,3.5)(1.12,3.4)(1.04,3.22)
\qbezier(1.04,3.22)(0.97,3.07)(0.87,3.07)
\qbezier(0.87,3.07)(0.72,3.09)(0.77,3.32)
\put(0.95,3.27){\circle*{0.14}}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: David will be proud of you! Great!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I have to make up for my theft of the parabola question :)

Comment: Very fair from you, lol!

Comment: Impressive. Kind of weird though; that it's a vector but the Bézier curves aren't smooth, but built from multiple consecutive vertical line-segments/open-paths: https://i.imgur.com/Vl173iM.png