# Diagram for Interest Rate Swaps

Tags: diagrams

I want to create a diagram in order to explain IRS concept. I need something like this, but I don't know how to make it:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very simple diagram to do in TikZ. The manual has some very good tutorials. See also [Looking to draw this block diagram in Tikz](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/215207) or [Block diagram using TikZ](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/237765) or [Drawing a Block Diagram using TikZ](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/209355). And [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349371/2693) has a fantastic answer showing the steps and planning for this sort of diagram.  Once you've done that, post some code showing what you're having trouble with.

Comment: [This](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/nav1d/) is a good place to start from, it is almost what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning,calc,shadows}
\tikzset{
    bluenode/.style={
        draw,
        white,
        top color=blue!50!white,
        bottom color=blue!90!white,
        rounded corners,drop shadow
    },
    graynode/.style={
        draw,
        top color=gray!50!white!20,
        bottom color=gray!50!black!20,drop shadow
    }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sf]
\node[bluenode] (A) at (0,0) {\begin{tabular}{c}Counterparty\\ A\end{tabular}};
\node[bluenode,right=4cm of A] (B) {\begin{tabular}{c}Counterparty\\ B\end{tabular}};
\node[graynode,below=3cm of A] (A1){Floating};
\node[graynode,below=3cm of B] (B1){Fixed};
\draw[blue!70!white,-latex,thick] ($(A.east)+(0,0.2)$) -- ($(B.west)+(0,0.2)$)
node[midway,above]{Fixed rate 7.5\%};
\draw[blue!70!white,latex-,thick] ($(A.east)-(0,0.2)$) -- ($(B.west)-(0,0.2)$)
node[midway,below]{LIBOR$+0.50$\%};
\draw[-latex,thick] (A) -- (A1) node[midway,right]{LIBOR$+1.50$\%};
\draw[-latex,thick] (B) -- (B1) node[midway,left]{7.3\%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will find doing these things on your own is much more fun.