# draw in LaTeX WITHOUT using tikz or pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm typesetting a drawing for an assignment, but I can only change what's in `\begin{document}` -- that is, I can't add any packages or make any changes in the preamble. Unfortunately, the platform I'm working on doesn't have `tikz` or `pgfplots` installed, so is there a way I can make basic drawings without using either package? (e.g. drawing squares and points)

Comment: For simple diagrams you can use `picture` mode, which is in the LaTeX kernel. But without an example of what you need…

Comment: Or you could draw your images with tikz/pgfplots in an own document and add them as images to the document where you don't have control over the preamble.

Comment: Maybe you can use `pstricks`?

Comment: There are portable installations of TeX systems. you canuse them

Comment: I think that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390382/134574) might interest you. No packages needed!

Comment: you can do technical drawings such as [aircraft design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847) without using any packages

Comment: Although the question been closed... I found a way to use Ti*k*Z without `\usepackage`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I know you are joking but It would not make it. How could you handle `\RequirePackage{tikz}` after document begin?

Comment: @Symbol1 Of course, I was joking, but since my comment may be misleading I deleted it :):):)

Comment: @Symbol1 BTW, I voted to reopen the question because it is different from the duplicate one. The question is something like: _I can't modify the preamble, how can I use some package like `tikz` or `pstricks`?_

Comment: @Henri-Menke I'm not sure a question on how to draw just using latex without packages should be closed as a duplicate of a question about which packages are available

Answer (score 3):

Assume the following:

- `xcolor` is in your preamble, or you know how to define `\colorlet`;
- you can copy files to the working directory (the one that `\includegraphics` will search in),

Then you can still `\input` necessary PGF files manually. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\def\ProvidesPackageRCS#1$#2${}
\def\ProvidesFileRCS#1$#2${}
\long\def\AtBeginDocument#1{}
\def\RequirePackage#1{}
\def\EveryShipout#1{}
\makeatletter
\input{pgfutil-common.tex}
\input{pgfutil-latex.def}
\input{pgfsys.code.tex}
\input{pgfcore.code.tex}
\input{pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex}
\input{pgfsysprotocol.code.tex}
\input{pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex}


A rectangle
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-60pt}{-5pt}}{\pgfpoint{60pt}{20pt}}
\pgfsetcolor{red}\pgfusepath{draw}
\pgfsetcolor{black}

$$$$

A point
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{5pt}
\pgfusepath{fill}

$$$$

A curve
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{10pt}{10pt}}{\pgfpoint{20pt}{-10pt}}{\pgfpoint{30pt}{00pt}}
\pgfusepath{draw}


\end{document}
```

[image]

You can further input Ti*k*Z if necessary.

```
\input pgffor.code.tex

A lot of points
\par\foreach\n in{1,...,200}{
    \xdef\n{\n}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{cos(\n r)*sqrt(\n)*10+200}\xdef\x{\x}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{sin(\n r)*sqrt(\n)*10-100}\xdef\y{\y}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\x pt}{\y pt}}{2pt}
}
\pgfusepath{draw}

\vskip300pt

\input pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
\input tikz.code.tex

A plot
\tikz\draw[scale=3,domain=0:4,samples=300]plot({cos(3*\x r)},{sin(5*\x r)});
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you forgot `\makeatother` after `\input`ting the `pgf` files.

Comment: @campa, it is not needed as well as `\makeatletter` is superfluous.

Comment: @Zarko You were right. I added it when I was searching for the shortest list of `\input` --- some files are supposed to be included by the root so they do not bother to make at letter again.

Comment: @Zarko I am not convinced. The first included file alone redefines the catcode of `@`. If I take the code in the answer and remove `\makeatletter` and add a macro `\fo@` I get the error `Undefined \fo@` and not `undefined \fo`, which clearly indicates that `@` is still considered a letter. Unless of course I am greatly misunderstanding something.

Comment: @campa, sorry but this i can't find in answer code. probably i miss something. also i didn't test the solution (since i'm sure that shoved images are produced with this code.